# Pass []string to a function that expects a variadic parameter

Tags: go

In order to don't repeat my self over and over I wanted to create a function that handles running some commands.

```
func runCommand(name string, arg ...string) error {
    cmd := exec.Command(name, arg)
    if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        return err
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Once I try to run this I get the following error:

```
cannot use arg (type []string) as type string in argument to exec.Command
```

I had a look into the implementation of the [`os.Command`](https://golang.org/src/os/exec/exec.go?s=3999:4044#L112) and it looks that the function signature is exact what I supply.

Internally a `[]string` should be the same as variadic parameter but for the compiler it seems not.

Is there a way to pass the variadic parameter into the `Command`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You expand the `[]string` with another `...`

```
cmd := exec.Command(name, arg...)
```

From the [language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec) on [Passing arguments to ... parameters](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters)

> If the final argument is assignable to a slice type `[]T`, it may be
>   passed unchanged as the value for a `...T` parameter if the argument is
>   followed by `...`. In this case no new slice is created.
>
> Given the slice s and call
>
> ```
> s := []string{"James", "Jasmine"}
> Greeting("goodbye:", s...)
> ```
>
> within Greeting, `who` will have the same value as `s` with the same underlying array.

Comment: This works fine. I have tried all kind of weird castings... never thought it could be that easy! Thank you very much!