# Can golang take a function with unknown number of parameters as an argument to another function

Tags: reflection, go, interface

Suppose I have a program like below

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    Execute(1,One)
//  Execute(2,Two)
//  Execute(3,Three)
}

type Executable func(int)

func Execute(noOfArgs int, fn Executable){
    switch noOfArgs {
        case 1 : fn(1)
//      case 2 : fn(1,2)
//      case 3 : fn("1",2,3)
    }
}
func One(n int) {
    fmt.Println("Foo = ",n)
}
func Two(n1,n2 int) {
    fmt.Println("Foo = ",n1+n2)
}
func Three(n1 string,n2,n3 int) {
    fmt.Println("Foo = ",n1+n2+n3)
}
```

And I would like to make the `Execute` function as a generic one which can receive functions with different number of arguments of different types, what should be the type of `Executable` ?

In other words, If I uncomment the commented lines in the above program, it will break. What modification should I make to the line `type Executable func(int)` to make it working?

**PS : Please try to give a generic answer instead of giving a workaround for the exact scenario which I mentioned**

EDIT:- This is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32721066/pass-string-to-a-function-that-expects-a-variadic-parameter) question.
I am not looking for expanding arguments. I will have **different types** of arguments and different number of arguments

EDIT:- I will explain my scenario more clearly.

I have a BDD style test executor which parses a line of text and execute the function associated with it, with appropriate arguments.

Eg :-

> Say "greeting" to "someone"

and an associated function

```
func SayGreeting(greeting, person string) {
    fmt.Println(greeting, ", ", person)
}
```

another line which says

> Add <2> , <3> and <4>

and associated function

```
func AddNum(n1, n2, n3 int) {
    sum := n1 + n2 + n3
    fmt.Println("Sum is : ", sum)
}
```

I have a mechanism to scan all the functions and add it to a map, with associated scenario. My program knows which function to execute, number of arguments to it and the arguments.

My problem is, how do I make the map generic so that I can store different functions with different number/type of arguments.

Comment: You have `reflection` and `interface` tags, but neither topic is in your question. The "generic" answer is use variadic functions. Can you explain why you don't want to use variadic functions? `func Three` isn't valid, so I'm not sure what you want to accomplish by mixing types.

Comment: [`type Executable func(...int)`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types) ?

Comment: @JimB Suppose my function Three is 

func Three(n1 string,n2 bool,n3 int) {
    fmt.Println("Foo = ",n1, n2, n3)
}

in such a case I can not use varargs right?

Comment: What you have here is a contrived example, which doesn't really make sense. You're fighting the type system for some reason, but I'm not sure why. Do you just want `type Executable func(...interface{})`?

Comment: As @JimB mentionned, I think you want to use the `interface{}` type. This allows to have different number of arguments with different types. Or depending on what you're really trying to achieve you could also use `...CustomInterface{}` and define your own interface that is useful for your function.

Answer (score 3):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func Simple(args ...interface{}) {
    fmt.Println("Foo =", fmt.Sprint(args...))
}

func main() {
    Execute(1, Simple)
    Execute(2, Simple)
    Execute(3, Simple)
}

type Executable func(...interface{})

func Execute(noOfArgs int, fn Executable) {
    switch noOfArgs {
    case 1:
        fn(1)
    case 2:
        fn(1, 2)
    case 3:
        fn("1", 2, 3)
    }
}
```

I quite don't know what you're trying to achieve here. You **can** take an unknown number of arguments with unknown types. But you shouldn't. What you **can and should** do is take an unknown number of arguments that are satisfying a custom interface you wrote and that will be used inside your function, otherwise it doesn't make sense and will, at one point force you to use reflection to know the type of an argument.

There is no point in using a strongly typed language if you try to avoid the types.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to "the exact scenario mentioned" is:

**No** **you** **cannot** **do** **this.**

(Especially as you shouldn't.)

Comment: i Just saw rob pike video ,https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAAkCSZUG1c
Hes asking people do not use reflection...

Comment: As @Depado's answer clearly shows, you can do it. Maybe you just wanted to say "the language's type system was not designed for that, so you should not do it".

Comment: @StefanoMozart No I wanted to say "No you cannot". Depadas answer is a limited instance of the general problem as f(a ...X) is a function with one parameter of type []X.